# Does PDO bindParam allow not existent variables?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, pdo

As during development I set `error_reporting(-1);` so I was sure that every syntax error will be shown by PHP. It is, for example

```
echo $ttt;
```

of course it gives

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ttt in ...
```

In this piece of code (a part of some class representing a row in mysql table):

```
public function delete(){
// ...
  $sth=$dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM tobjects WHERE IdObject=:id');
  $sth->bindParam(':id',$this->fid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $sth->execute();
```

I mistyped what is now `$this->fid` and the deletion did not occur, no error was even to be noticed, and I spent long time to find it.

The `$dbh` is set elsewhere as:

```
$dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=XXXX;port=XXXX;dbname=XXXX",$db_user,
$db_password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Am I doing something wrong or how is it possible that no error was given?

Comment: *"Am I doing something wrong?"*, well you set the error mode to exception but do not use any try/catch block to catch those exceptions...

Comment: It is not PDO that should give an error about this. As in your echo statement, it is php that should report it.

Comment: Yes but why PHP does not show notice: Undefined variable?

Comment: becaus is passing by reference

Comment: @WouterK yes, I know, it's development, it's not ready yet, however uncatched exception should be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't see the notice because the arguments of [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) are passed as reference.

```
function test(&$var) {
    // var may also be undefined
    var_dump($var);
}

test($undef);
```

This don't throw any error. Doc: [What References Do](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)